# Which UML Tool has been used to create this diagram?

Tags: uml

I would like to know which UML Sofware has been used to create the UML Diagram on the Wordpress Developper Website : http://codex.wordpress.org/images/8/83/WP_27_dbsERD.png

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It's an ERD, not UML ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like some old version of [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) to me. The new version creates more elegant pictures.

P.S. There are no actual foreign keys in WordPress, since they're based on MyISAM tables, so I guess those lines were drawn in Paint or smth :D

Answer (score 1):

OK I should have looked a little more.

The answer is MySQL Workbench : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.0.html